# If vs try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

The [following code](https://gist.github.com/sampablokuper/b8fa8e49ae03a7ec290f), written in synchronous Node.js and intended to be used as a shell script, nests a try/catch inside a conditional.

Because both the conditional and the try/catch serve a similar purpose - respectively, check a file exists, and check that reading and writing to it succeeds - it feels clumsy that the code uses two different mechanisms. The nesting may also be unnecessary.

**What would be a more readable way to write this code?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

var path = process.argv[2];
var data = "#!/usr/bin/env node\n\n";
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  try {
    data += fs.readFileSync(path);
    fs.writeFileSync(path, data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Problem reading or writing " + path + " : " + err.message)
    process.exit(1);
  }
} else {
  console.log("Invalid path");
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a good strategy is to return early as soon as you detect an error.  Putting the error handler for `fs.existSync(path)` in an `else` block far away from where the check occurred makes the code harder to follow, and increases the amount of nesting required.

Also, the error message should inform the user of *which* path is invalid.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');

var path = process.argv[2];
var data = "#!/usr/bin/env node\n\n";
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    console.log("Invalid path: " + path);
    process.exit(1);
}
try {
    data += fs.readFileSync(path);
    fs.writeFileSync(path, data);
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Problem reading or writing " + path + " : " + err.message)
    process.exit(1);
}
```